# Different constraint while editing and creating new record

Tags: symfony, doctrine, constraints

So basically I'm trying to add constraint on image properties. But the problem is that when I create a new post and I upload image the `file` property is filled. When I edit the post it has `path` property filled and not `file`. How can I solve this validation so the `path` or `file` is always required ? Currently if I edit the post I'll get validation error because `file` will be empty and `path` will not be empty

ArticleImage.php

```
/**
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     maxSize="1024k",
 *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"}
 * )
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $file;

/**
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $path;
```

Article.php entity has this property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Article", mappedBy="owner")
 */
private ?ImageInterface $image = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [constraint for the class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator), for example, File, that will check your fields. You can extend the symfony Image constraint and validator by your classes, in the validator you can do something like this

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!$constraint instanceof File) {
        throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, File::class);
    }

    if (!$value instanceof SomeClass) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$value->getPath() && !$value->getFile()) {
        $this->context->buildViolation('empty file')
            ->atPath('file')
            ->addViolation();

        return;
    }

    if ($value->getFile()) {
        // will validate your image
        parent::validate($value->getFile(), $constraint);

        return;
    }
}
```

Or you can use [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)